# The content of element type "details" must match

Tags: xml, validation, dtd

I am currently trying to validate my XML file with https://www.xmlvalidation.com but I keep getting this message

```
16: 12  The content of element type "details" must match "(code+,title+,size+,price+,salePrice+,glazeType+,description+,image+)".
```

My DTD is

```
<!ELEMENT catalog (details+)>
<!ELEMENT details (code+,title+,size+,price+,salePrice+,glazeType+,description+,image+)>
<!ELEMENT code (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT title (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT size (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT price (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT salePrice (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT glazeType (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT description (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT image (#PCDATA)>
```

and my XML

```
<details>
    <code>bcpot020</code>
    <title>Copper Red Dish 001</title>
    <size>50cm diameter</size>
    <price>$450.00</price>
    <glazeType>Copper Red</glazeType>
    <description>Shallow Copper Red dish form showing distinctive qualities of this traditional reduction fired glaze. Fired to 1300 degrees</description>
    <image>images/Copper Red Dish 001.jpg</image>
</details>

<details>
    <code>bcpot003</code>
    <title>Copper Red Bottle 001</title>
    <size>60cm tall</size>
    <price>$550.00</price>
    <salePrice>$475.00</salePrice>
    <glazeType>Copper Red</glazeType>
    <description>Copper Red bottle form. Reduction fired to 1300 degrees</description>
    <image>images/Copper Red Bottle 001.jpg</image>
</details>
```

Any suggestions on how to fix this error?

Comment: In the first `<details>` element `<salePrice>` is missing. Does adding that fix your issue?

Answer (score 0):

The DTD requires one or more `salePrice` elements but your first `details` element has none.

Either change the DTD to make the element optional (e.g. change '+' to '*'), or add a salePrice element to the instance.